# In a prometheus query it cannot be filtered with the worker nodes tag

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

We are implementing a prometheus query to let us know when the requests in the cluster nodes are high. We have tried filtering the worker role: but why

```
namespace_cpu:kube_pod_container_resource_requests:sum{kubernetes_node_role=~"worker"}
```

gives no datapoints and

```
namespace_cpu:kube_pod_container_resource_requests:sum
```

```
Element Value
namespace_cpu:kube_pod_container_resource_requests:sum{namespace="aaaaa-dev"}   2.4
namespace_cpu:kube_pod_container_resource_requests:sum{namespace="dev-xxxxx"}   0.8600000000000001
namespace_cpu:kube_pod_container_resource_requests:sum{namespace="dev-yyyyy"}   1.2100000000000006
namespace_cpu:kube_pod_container_resource_requests:sum{namespace="dev-zzzzz"}   0.6
```

does? In the scrape config of prometheus we didn't find information enough to fix this

Note:

```
namespace_cpu:kube_pod_container_resource_requests:sum{kubernetes_node_role=~".*worker.*"}
```

This is giving no datapoints too

Comment: Could you see if the following articles are helpful in resolving the problem?
1) https://logz.io/blog/promql-examples-introduction/#func. 
2) https://www.section.io/blog/prometheus-querying/

Comment: Thanks :) I read the articles, but didn't help me writing the query so the data appear

Comment: Your metrics have only `namespace` label. You can't use non-existent labels (`kubernetes_node_role` here) to filter metrics.

Comment: Based on your metric naming I assume it is result of recording rules. Look into them maybe you are loosing needed labels on aggregation step there.