# how to configure a prometheus installation of openshift to include the labels of node role in the exporter?

Tags: openshift, prometheus

In this context ([What prometheus alert do you have configured in an openshift on premise cluster to automate node scaling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76383526/what-prometheus-alert-do-you-have-configured-in-an-openshift-on-premise-cluster) and [In a prometheus query it cannot be filtered with the worker nodes tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76270088/in-a-prometheus-query-it-cannot-be-filtered-with-the-worker-nodes-tag)), how to configure a prometheus installation of openshift to include the labels of node role in the exporter?

We want to alert based on cpu requests only on worker nodes

namespace_cpu:kube_pod_container_resource_requests:sum{kubernetes_node_role=~"worker"}

gives no datapoints and

```
namespace_cpu:kube_pod_container_resource_requests:sum
```

```
Element Value
namespace_cpu:kube_pod_container_resource_requests:sum{namespace="aaaaa-dev"}   2.4
namespace_cpu:kube_pod_container_resource_requests:sum{namespace="dev-xxxxx"}   0.8600000000000001
namespace_cpu:kube_pod_container_resource_requests:sum{namespace="dev-yyyyy"}   1.2100000000000006
namespace_cpu:kube_pod_container_resource_requests:sum{namespace="dev-zzzzz"}   0.6
```

I have reviewed this documentation without success
[1] https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/install_config/prometheus_cluster_monitoring.html
[2] https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/

Comment: First of all, you'd better clarify what you want to achieve in greater details. Like what node roles are, how dynamic are they, and so on. Second, I'd argue this kind of question is way more suited for something like [sf] or [devops.se].